# Filter archetypes in Maven command line with archetype:generate

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-archetype

When trying to generate a Maven project from an archetype (using `mvn archetype:generate`), the command returns a **lots** of archetypes.

Is there a way to **filter** archetypes given a word (contained in groupId or artifactId)?

I know you can actually create a project with a specific archetype, with arguments like `-DgroupID=org.domain -DartifactId=sample`, but it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok. A [bug as been filed](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ARCHETYPE-371) and should be resolved in Maven archetype plugin version 2.1.

Edit:

Bug is solved in maven-archetype-plugin version 2.1. [Documentation is ready](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/usage.html).

```
mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=org.apache:struts
```

For a `groupId` containing `org.apache` AND an `artifactId` containing `struts`